# How to efficiently fill in missing rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am given a dataframe that both have rows I don't care about and is often missing rows. I want to remove the unnecessary rows and add the missing rows in an efficient manner. Here's an example of code that does what I want to do to a toy example:

```
# df1 has data for rows I don't care about (index > 4), but only has even values
# df1 is created inside a black box (for me)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,2,4,6,8], columns=['Data'], data=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

# I construct a new dataframe so the index contains all and only the rows I want
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2,3,4], columns=['Data'])

# This assignment is slow
df2['Data'] = df1['Data']
return df2
```

The result (df2) is exactly what I want:

```
    Data
0   a
1   NaN
2   b
3   NaN
4   c
```

But that last line `df2['Data'] = df1['Data']` is taking about 30s to execute on the real data. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: The nature of the missing rows, in reality, is apparently arbitrary. In the example, I chose to use only even indices, but that was just to create the example, not indicative of any patterns in the actual data.

Comment: Maybe: `df1.reindex_like(df2)`

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs the fact that your suggestion takes a similar amount of time makes me think there might not be much better option.

Comment: I was worried that might be the case... I don't know of any other improvements, sorry :(

Comment: why the need of `df2`? wouldn't `df1.reindex(np.arange(4))` work?

Comment: Yes, a simple reindex call seems to be the cleanest way to do this, even if there don't seem to be speed benefits. Many thanks.